# undefined reference when using library inside library (vycode, cpp)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, undefined-reference

I am trying to create a CANInterface library using PCANBasic. The library is build with CMake whithout indicating problems.
When I try to compile (*g++ -o Testing Testing.cpp -L/home/gary/Desktop/VSCode/Testing -lCANInterface*) a testproram, which is using libCANInterface.a, I get

```
/usr/bin/ld: /home/gary/Desktop/VSCode/Testing/libCANInterface.a(CANInterface.cpp.o): in function `CAN::InitPCAN()':
/home/gary/Desktop/VSCode/CANInterface/CANInterface.cpp:154: undefined reference to `CAN_Initialize'
(and similar for other used functions from PCANBasic)
```

CMakeList.txt (for generating libCANInterface.a)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(CANInterface)
add_library(CANInterface CANInterface.cpp)
find_library(lib_path pcanbasic)
target_link_libraries(CANInterface "${lib_path}")
find_path(header_path CANInterface)
target_include_directories(CANInterface PUBLIC "${header_path}")
```

sample of usage of functions CANInterface.cpp

```
#include "PCANBasic.h"
...

void CAN::InitPCAN() {
    // The Plug & Play Channel (PCAN-USB) is initialized
    result = CAN_Initialize(PCAN_USBBUS1, PCAN_BAUD_500K);
    if (result != PCAN_ERROR_OK)
    {
        // An error occurred, get a text describing the error and show it
        CAN_GetErrorText(result, 0, strMsg);
        printf("strMsg %s \n", strMsg);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("PCAN-USB was initialized \n");
        bInitialized = true;
    }
}
```

Testing.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "CANInterface.h"


int main() {
    vehicle vVehicle;

    vVehicle.read();

    return 0;
}
```